# Does angularjs template need to be routed through nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, request, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using node.js to host my angular website. My angular directive is not working properly because it cannot be displayed when I run my website.

Node http server is used to handle the routes. With `console.log(req.url)` I'm able to see all requests urls, but there isn't one that should look like `/app-get.html` :

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url)
    if(req.url == '/'){
        fs.readFile('./src/index.html', (err, file) => {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
            res.write(file)
            res.end()
        })
    }
    if(req.url == '/angular.min.js'){
        fs.readFile('./src/angular.min.js', (err, file) => {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'})
            res.write(file)
            res.end()
        })
    }
}).listen(9999)
```

Can I even use templateUrl in angular directive to load html file without configuring server route for that file (`app-get.html`)?

```
app.directive("getApp", function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app-get.html'
    }
})
```

Comment: Right, but there isn't such request made to server. I would like to know how angular is making request for template. I hope its the similar as if I would include source of css or script file inside html.

Comment: If there is no request, then it likely the directive isn't being instantiated. Check the HTML for typos, missing `ng-app` directive, incorrect normalization of the directive name, etc. Finally put a `console.log` in the directive to verify that the directive is being instantiated.

Comment: So I made a route after I was able to see request for html file related to angular directive, but the problem is that this directive only works after it is initialised inside main index.html page, in <script> tag. If I try to initialise it inside its own "script.js" file I get error SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr]...

Comment: You really should do a `res.sendHead(404,"Not found").end()` for unknown routes.  The method, [`response.end()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback), MUST be called on each response. Otherwise the request and its response hangs.

Comment: The [$injector:modulerr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr)  error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message should provide additional context.
A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

Comment: You will get better error messages if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`. Also there will be alot more [debugging data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) which will make debugging from the Developer Console easier.